How to count a measure?
I'm having a problem and would like to know if you can help me again. I have a table as follows:



Date
Data
Measure




23/05/24
126
0.41


24/05/24
356
0.50


25/05/24
789
-0.33


26/05/24
568
-0.04


27/05/24
4785
0.10


28/05/24
25
-0.02


29/05/24
365
-0.12


30/05/24
1
-0.40


31/05/24
55
0.30


01/06/24
364
0.56



The second column contains some data I have, and the third one is a measure created from the data. I need to create a measure that gives me, for each day, how many of the values in the "Measure" column in the last 7 days (including the current day) are below -0.10. The result would be something like:



Date
Data
Measure
New_measure




23/05/24
126
0.41
0


24/05/24
356
0.50
0


25/05/24
789
-0.33
1


26/05/24
568
-0.04
1


27/05/24
4785
0.10
1


28/05/24
25
-0.02
1


29/05/24
365
-0.12
2


30/05/24
1
-0.40
3


31/05/24
55
0.30
3


01/06/24
364
0.56
2



Additionally, these data must respond to some slicers I have with filters.
What I tried was something like:
New_measure = 
VAR aux_table = ADDCOLUMNS(
                    SUMMARIZE(
                    ALLSELECTED('table'),
                    'table'[Date]),
                    "Measure_aux", [Measure])
VAR max_day = MAX([Date])
 
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(
        FILTER(
            aux_table,
            [Measure_aux] < -0.1 &&
            [Date] >= max_day-6 &&
            [Date] <= max_day
        )
    )
)

But it doesn't work correctly. Does anyone have any idea how I can do this or what I did wrong?

why for 1/6/2024 the new column is 2? What's the calculation logic?

Because only 30/05 and 29/05 are < -0.1 in the last 7 days (from 26/05 to 1/06).

Try modifying this line:
VAR aux_table = ADDCOLUMNS(
                    SUMMARIZE(
                    ALLSELECTED('table'),
                    'table'[Date]),
                    "Measure_aux", [Measure])

To:
VAR aux_table =
  SUMMARIZE(
    ALLSELECTED('table'),
    'table'[Date],
    "Measure_aux", [Measure]
  )

